# Can I know what's the structure of the original object/function called and the name of this structure?

Tags: javascript

I have seen the code line below in Javascript but I don't know the name of this way in making objects and functions?

Would you please hint how to write the object/function which is called by the line below?

```
var generalSettings = new (invoke("settings"))({"a":1}).push(5);
```

I was unable to search about this, I read about OOP in Javascript but never seen this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `invoke("settings")` returns a constructor function. In turn, that constructor function receives an argument: the object `{"a":1}`. Finally, that resulting object produced by that constructor function has its `push` method invoked.

```
// this accepts an object with an `a` key, like {"a":1}
// it constructs an object with an `aVal` property and `push` method
function SettingsObj(options) {
    this.aVal = options.a;
    this.push = function() { /* ... */ };
}

// this object serves as a dictionary of constructors
var constructors = {
    "settings": SettingsObj
}

// this function returns a constructor from the constructors dictionary
function invoke(constructorName) {
    return constructors[constructorName];
}
```

- `invoke("settings")` - returns a constructor
- `new (invoke("settings"))()` - runs the constructor with no arguments
- `new (invoke("settings"))({"a":1})`  - runs the constructor one `{"a":1}` argument
- `new (invoke("settings"))({"a":1}).push(5)` - calls the `push` method on the object built by the constructor

Comment: Thank you very much for making it very clear! I just tested and it worked fine :)